# php autocomplete return checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery-autocomplete

I want to return data to checkbox. If data equal value of checkbox is checked.
Data return is json and script checkbox is not work. Please help me!!!!
Ex. 
if return com_cate=1

checkbox is check

This code autocomplete.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js-autocomplete/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/js-autocomplete/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      $('.company_name').autocomplete({
         source:'return-company.php', 
         //minLength:2,
         select:function(evt, ui){
            this.form.id_company.value = ui.item.id_company;
            this.form.com_contact.value = ui.item.com_contact;
            this.form.company_address.value = ui.item.company_address;
            this.form.id_contact.value = ui.item.id_contact;
            this.form.company_tel.value = ui.item.company_tel;
            this.form.company_fax.value = ui.item.company_fax;
            this.form.mobile.value = ui.item.mobile;
            this.form.company_email.value = ui.item.company_email;
            this.form.com_cate.value = ui.item.com_cate;    

            /*check box */  
           if (this.form.com_cate.value == "1") {
              $('.com_cate').prop('checked', true);
           } else {
              $('.com_cate').prop('checked', false);
           }
       }
   });
});
</script> 
<input type="checkbox" name="com_cate" id="com_cate" class="com_cate" value="1">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (this.form.com_cate.value == "1") {
         Print '<input type="checkbox" name="com_cate" id="com_cate" class="com_cate" value="1" checked="yes">'
       } else {
         Print '<input type="checkbox" name="com_cate" id="com_cate" class="com_cate" value="1">'
       }
```

Simple solution? Just change your JS to PHP!